# '/usr/local/var/run/libvirt/libvirt-sock': No such file or directory

Tags: terminal, homebrew

I installed `libvirt`:

```
brew libvirt
```

For starting it I am using:

```
brew services start libvirt
```

But it is not creating the socket, after running for example:

```
virsh -c qemu:///system
```

I get:

```
'/usr/local/var/run/libvirt/libvirt-sock': No such file or directory
```

I already modified/edit the file `/opt/homebrew/etc/libvirt/libvirtd.conf` with this options:

```
listen_tls = 0
listen_tcp = 1
unix_sock_group = "libvirt"
unix_sock_ro_perms = "0777"
unix_sock_rw_perms = "0770"
unix_sock_admin_perms = "0700"
unix_sock_dir = "/opt/homebrew/var/run/libvirt"
auth_unix_ro = "none"
auth_unix_rw = "none"
auth_tcp = "none"
```

But still can't create the socket.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `qemu://session?socket=/opt/homebrew/var/run/libvirt/libvirt-sock`.

p.s. in your ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bashrc, you can put

```bash
export LIBVIRT_DEFAULT_URI="qemu://session?socket=$(brew --prefix)/var/run/libvirt/libvirt-sock"
```